# Legend in storymap show correct hexcode colours in editor but not in final display

Tags: arcgis-online, legend, html, css, story-map

I have used some html/css code from here: https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/12/16/enhance-legend-story-map-journal/

to display legends in a journal style storymap. The hexcodes are correct and show the right colour in the editor like below:
[image: Image of correct colours in editor]

and when I save the output to my storymap looks like this:
[image]

Does anyone know why the colours and text would change and move? I have other legends in the story map and they are fine. It seems to affect the blue and yellow colours only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to HTML code so I was on the wrong track - I was looking at different ways to change sRGB and RGB to the correct hex codes (there is slightly different versions that can look a little different on different browsers).

Here is a sample of the below code:

```
}

.legendbox.symyellow {

 background-color: #eaeb83;

}
```

I had symcolour as well as the hex code. What was being applied, from what I could tell was the symcolour instead of the hexcode so when I had two legends with the same sym code e.g symblue it applied that to both legends. I kept the hexcodes the same and put in unique symcolour codes which corrected my colours